# Parsing complicated string-based configuration options

Tags: python, data-conversion, universe

I'm trying to build a Python program that will parse the conversion codes from a Universe Database.  These conversion codes are highly dense strings that encode a ton of information, and I'm struggling to get started.  The different permutations of the conversion codes likely number in the hundreds of thousands (though I haven't done the math).

I'm familiar with `argparse`, however I can't come up with a way of handling this kind of parsing with `argparse`, and my Google-fu hasn't come up with any other solution.

Initially, my lazy work around was to just do a dictionary lookup for the most common conversion codes, but now that we're using this Python program for more data, it's becoming a huge chore to maintain each individual conversion code.

For example, date conversion codes may take forms like:

- Date: `D[n][*m][s][fmt[[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]]][E][L]`, e.g. `D2/` or `D4-2/RM`
- Datetime: `DT[4|D|4D|T|TS|Z][;timezone]`, e.g. `DTZ` or `DT4;America/Denver`
- Datetime ISO: `DTI[B][R|W][S][Z][2|1|0][;[timezone|offset]]`, e.g. `DTIBZ2` or `DTIR;America/Denver`

And there are a bunch of other conversion codes, with equally complicated parameters.

My end goal is to be able to convert Universe's string data into the appropriate Python object and back again, and in order to do that, I need to understand these conversion codes.

If it helps, I do not need to validate these conversion codes.  Once they are set in the database, they are validated there.

Comment: I don't see how argparse is relevant here unless you are receiving these conversion codes as a command line argument. If that's the case, argparse has no builtin types to handle these codes, but you could make a parsing function that will be used by a custom argparse type. Can you include a description or a link to some documentation that explains the conversion codes? That would allow users that are unfamiliar with universe conversion codes to help. Please provide some sample input and expected output for a parsing function, as well.

Comment: If you have been at this awhile you might not know about UOPY as I think it was released late last year.. https://pypi.org/project/uopy/ It know it has ICONV and OCONV functionality which I think will get you where you want to be without having to maintain anything.

Comment: @VanAmburg I am familiar with UOPY, but it unfortunately does not accomplish what I need.  Perhaps I'm missing something, but the issue I'm having is that UOPY and U2PY both just return data as strings, and I have no way (other than conversion codes) to understand what object they actually contain.  Likewise, when I go to write the data back, I need to know the proper string format to give Universe, or else it does not properly store the data.  A good example is dates/times: I want to "read" a field and get a Python datetime object, and likewise I want to write in a datetime object.

Comment: You can use the conversion code as a hint to what the underlying data structure should be. In your example, if the code starts with DT, it should be a UTC time stamp and you can ignore the conversion entirely and use datetime.utcfromtimestamp to get an object. You might lose some context, but ideally the context doesn't matter as much at the level you are working at. Check the list of Conversion Codes in the back of the Basic guide against your current map. You will mostly probably care about the Ms and the Ds. Be REAL careful with MD as that is where the money goes. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the readnamedfields/writenamedfields methods, this will return OCONV data, and when you write back it handles the ICONV.

> > > import u2py
> > > help( u2py.File.readnamedfields)
> > > Help on function readnamedfields in module u2py:

readnamedfields(self, *args)
F.readnamedfields(recordid, fieldnnames, [lockflag]) -> new DynArray object -- read the specified fields by name of a record in the file

```
fieldnames is a u2py.DynArray object with each of its fields being a name defined in the dictionary file
lockflag is either 0 (default), or [LOCK_EXCLUSIVE or LOCK_SHARED] [ + LOCK_WAIT]

note: if fieldnames contains names that are not defined in the dictionary, these names are replaced by @ID and no exception is raised
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This is what I'm doing already, and where I'm running into my problem:  the only thing I get is a string.  This is particularly problematic when I'm dealing with datetime objects.  Not all Universe Date/Time oconv are automagically parsed by the Python datetime library.  And if the datetime object I attempt to write into Universe contains extra data (like milliseconds), u2py fails to write silently without writing anything.